# counting the number of a specific word in one SQL column

Tags: table, count

I'm trying to make a survey like a referundum to know if my neighboors in my small building are for or against a colectif compost to reduce the organics wastes.

For this tool vote I'm using PHP and SQL, my database is build like this:

DBNAME=collectifCompost
Table=voteCompost

column1=id PRIMARY AI

column2=user

column3=vote(yes/no/blank)

To build a chart with statistics vote results (% of YES, NO, BLANK..) I want to make a query on my database to count the number of YES NO AND BLANK but I don't know how. Can you help me please?

If you need more information about my code ask me everything.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
select   vote, count(*)
from     voteCompost
group by vote;
```

Now you get the number of rows per `vote` value.

Comment: This will not count the number of null values.

Comment: select   vote, count("I have to putt a value YES,NO, BLANK here?")
from     voteCompost
group by vote;

Comment: Thank you for your help a_horse_with_no_name but I think with PHP I will make a short calcul to return the numbers of blank vote. I hope...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I changed the `count(vote)` into `count(*)`. Now the **NULL** values are counted. The OP did not mention that `vote` could be **NULL**.

Comment: $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT  COUNT(vote) AS totalYes from compost WHERE vote="yes"'); and the same request for each choice(yes,no,blank). Thank you for your help!